# August 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  10pm UTC / 6pm EDT on the 16th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the [moderator elections](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/2), we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 16th at 10pm UTC / 6pm EDT.**

[**view in other timezones**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=8&day=16&year=2011&hour=22&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

[**register here**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/269/gaming-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)

### Read this next part, it is important!

> If you would like to pose a question to one/some/all of the [candidates](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/2), **you must post it in [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1082/gaming-town-hall-chat-questions)**.  Please star questions asked by others if you'd like it to be asked.  I'll take the highest voted questions and ask them during the [town hall chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/269/gaming-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. Since it isn't clear whether or not there will be a primary phase, I have to operate on the assumption that there won't be.  This means that I am looking at the 16th-18th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gaming.stackexchange.com).
- <s>The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.</s> See updated note above.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: So the last time we did this there was an issue with multiple people asking questions at the same time and candidates trying to sort that out.  I feel like having a seperate room where people ask questions from the main town hall room would be useful.  Then a moderator could ask the question to all the candidates in the town hall room, which would give the opportunity for discussion, instead of people being forced on to the next question which was asked too quickly.

Comment: Why not have a Meta question where users can suggest questions (much like Google Moderator) and then everyone votes up the good questions?

Comment: @IvoFlipse: We want actual users to ask this question rather than the nominees themselves, the only way to do this properly is by putting out a system message that asks for people to place questions. But even then, it requires them to bypass the answers-get-converted-to-comments system and then people have to actually vote for the questions (while I believe that the amount of questions isn't that high). I think it's best to have tzenes' proposal of splitting them up by adding a queue...

Comment: In case anyone doesn't see it and is confused when I don't participate: I've withdrawn my nomination.  There are at least three candidates better qualified to mod Gaming than me, and all would be excellent moderators. Since I already moderate two sites I would prefer to add one of these wonderful people as a mod than obstruct their progression, I think that will only benefit us.

Comment: I'm withdrawing for the same reason as Matthew Read; I can also better focus myself on the community I spent the most time which is Super User rather than trying to help Gaming *too much*, which only makes me hit a brick wall because I've not been a resident since the first days which resulted in unnecessary edits being rolled back. This is a bad sign for a nominee; so, I will most likely not nominate myself again over the next years but you will still see me give regular answers on games I know. In any case, lessons learned and the Town Hall did a great job making me think about moderating.

Answer (score 3):

For the candidates who are not able to make the Town Hall, is there an approved way for us to give our answers?  Like can we just post them as answers in this question (after you have selected the official questions)?

Comment: Add them as answers in the chat room later that night or the next day and they'll be added in to the digest that will be posted here on meta.  Please use the explicit replies so that the messages link back to the question you're responding to to help us out.